Which PnL is correct?
Suppose that

There is a risky asset whose value at time $t$ is $S_t$.
The interest rate is constant equal to $r$.
There are three timestamps $t_0=0$, $t_1=\delta t$ and $t_2=2\delta t$.

I am interested in knowing the PnL between $t_0$ and $t_2$ of being long one unit of risky asset. However I have two contradictory reasonings:
I_ What I was told at school
At time $t$, your portfolio has value $V_t$. Then your PnL between $t_0$ and $t_2$ is $V_{t_2}-V_0$. Here:

At time $t_0$ I borrow $S_0$ dollars to buy one unit of risky asset, hence $V_0=S_0-S_0=0$.
At time $t_2$, my risky asset is worth $S_{t_2}$, but I paid interest $S_0(1+r\delta t)^2$ on the money I borrowed, hence $V_{t_2}=S_{t_2}-S_0(1+r\delta t)^2$.

The PnL is therefore $S_{t_2}-S_0(1+r\delta t)^2$.
II_ What I am told at work
The PnL between $t$ and $T$ is the sum of all incrementals PnLs. That is if we denote by $PnL_{u\to v}$ the PnL between times $u$ and $v$, then
$$
PnL_{t\to T}=\sum_{s=t}^{T-\delta t}PnL_{s\to s+\delta t}.
$$
And the incremental PnL of a long strategy between $t$ and $t+\delta t$ is calculated as the profit made by borrowing the money to buy the risky assets at $t$, then selling out your position at $t+\delta t$. So in my example:

PnL between $0$ and $\delta t$: at 0 you borrow $S_0$ dollars to buy one unit of risky asset. At $\delta t$ you sell out. The unit of risky asset is worth $S_{t_1}$, and the interest you paid is $S_0(1+r\delta t)$. Hence $PnL_{0,\delta t}=S_{t_1}-S_0-S_0r\delta t$.
PnL between $\delta t$ and $2\delta t$ : at $\delta t$ you borrow $S_{t_1}$ dollars to buy one unit of risky asset. At $t_2$ you sell out. The unit of risky asset is worth $S_{t_2}$, and the interest you paid is $S_{t_1}(1+r\delta t)$. Hence $PnL_{t_1\to t_2}=S_{t_2}-S_{t_1}-S_{t_1}r\delta t$.

We deduce the global PnL:
$$
PnL_{0\to t_2}=S_{t_2}-S_0r\delta t-S_{t_1}r\delta t.
$$
Question
Those two PnLs do not coincide. Which one do you believe makes more sense? And is there a way to connect the two?
Any insight and/or reference on PnL computation would be much appreciated.

Did you not say initially that $V$ is self-financing? In that case there is no cost to finance it and the PnL is always just $V_T-V_t$ between any two time points.

When I mention cost of financing, in this context I mean how the performance compares to that of all the portfolio value invested in cash. At time $t$ you invest $V_t$ in risky asset so at $T$ you have a profit of $V_T-V_t$. But that is $V_t$ you could not invest in cash, which would have got you a profit of $V_tr(T-t)$, which is what I call cost of financing. Hence with that reasoning the incremental pnl is $V_T-V_t(1+r(T-t))$.

I am willing to give this a few more thoughts. In OP the risky asset was $P$ and at time $t$ we had a portfolio of $V_t=P_t+D_t,.$ Now you say $V_t$ is the risky asset. Very confusing. Edit the post to make this crystal clear. We can think about what is a PnL once we know what we have invested in.

Thank you for your comment, I completely rewrote the question which just focuses now on the simple example. If I understand the example, then I think I could understand the general case.

Quite naturally the two PnLs do not necessarily coincide. In the "school case" you don't touch the portfolio at $t_1=t+\delta t$ and liquidate it only at $t_2=t+2\delta t\,.$ In the "work case" you liquidate the portfolio at $t_1$ realising its PnL (let me simplify the notation a bit)
$$
PnL_1=S_{t_1}-S_{t_0}-S_{t_0}\,r\,\delta t\,.
$$
When you then set up the portfolio again by borrowing $S_{t_1}$ at rate $r$ you can realise a PnL at $t_2$ of
$$
PnL_2=S_{t_2}-S_{t_1}-S_{t_1}\,r\,\delta t\,.
$$
The question is what you did with the money $PnL_1\,.$ Did you spend it
when it was positive? I do not recommend that :).
To make the two methods comparable you should think of investing/borrowing $PnL_1$ at rate $r$ so that it stays in the system until $t_2\,.$ At that time your
net PnL is not $PnL_1+PnL_2$ but rather
$$\require{cancel}
PnL_1(1+r\delta t)+PnL_2=S_{t_2}-\cancel{S_{t_1}(1+r\delta t)}+\cancel{S_{t_1}(1+r\delta t)}
-S_{t_0}(1+r\delta t)^2\,$$
as expected from the "school case."

I should probably mention that I did not say which method is correct. Just wanted to give the reason why they are different.


Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer. Thanks to your last equality I understand that the "school case" pnl takes into account the performance of the cash investment of the profit made along the way, that is $PnL_1r\delta t$. So the "work case" pnl is the pnl stripped of cash interest performance, and only reflects the risky asset investment performance. I can understand why this is the pnl used in my company. Do you agree with this point of view?

I am not an accountant but I believe that these questions have more to do with conventions and being consistent to be able to tell if, say, last year's PnL was better or worse than this year's. There is probably no scientific way to derive a "correct" method. The above difference I rather see as follows: when we re-invest/re-borrow at $t_1$ to make both methods agree we make the "work case" self-financing. In contrast, your company opts to let intermediate gains/losses drop out. There could be reasons for this. Perhaps it is a method to calculate taxes? I don't know.

Makes sense. Thank you very much.
